# for loop for array to be displayed in different way

Tags: php, arrays

i want each of the arrays inside an array to be displayed inside an li such that 3 sub-arrays have 3 `<ul>`'s. However, the second and third value of each sub-array has to be inside the same `<li>`. like this:

```
natraj :
HB : Rs.10,
HH : Rs.12
```

I used a for loop where the output is comin like this:

```
  Natraj
    HB
    10
    HH
    12
```

and so on for other sub-arrays too. Please give a code similar to the one i used so i can understand this better. The code i used is:

```
   <?php
 $pencils = array( array("Natraj", "HB", 10, "HH", 12), array("Apsara", "HB", 8, "HH", 9), array("Camlin", "HB", 11, "HH", 13)  );
    //natraj :
    //HB : Rs.10,
    //HH : Rs.12 

    for ($pencilSet=0; $pencilSet<3; $pencilSet++){
    //echo $pencils[$pencilSet];
    echo "<ul>";

    //echo "<strong>", $pencils[$pencilSet], "</strong>";
    for($pencilSetDetials=0; $pencilSetDetials<5; $pencilSetDetials++){
    echo "<li>",$pencils[$pencilSet][$pencilSetDetials], "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$pencils = array( array("Natraj", "HB", 10, "HH", 12), array("Apsara", "HB", 8, "HH", 9), array("Camlin", "HB", 11, "HH", 13)  );

echo '<style>ul{list-style-type: none;}</style>';
foreach($pencils as $data) {
    echo '<ul>';
    $heading = array_shift($data); // get the item name heading
    $values = array_chunk($data, 2); // group by two's
    echo "<li><strong>$heading</strong></li>";
    foreach($values as $value) {
        list($type, $price) = $value;
        echo "<li>$type: Rs.$price</li>";
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing inner loop to this:

```
for($pencilSetDetials=0; $pencilSetDetials<5; $pencilSetDetials++){
    echo "<li>";
    echo  $pencils[$pencilSet][$pencilSetDetials];
    if($pencilSetDetials != 0){ //Donot run the condition if its the first element
         //Add 1 more the counter so we get the next value
         $pencilSetDetials++;
         //print the next value in the same li
         echo  ' : '.$pencils[$pencilSet][$pencilSetDetials];
    }
    echo  "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to change the inner for loop like this :

```
<?php
$pencil = array
   (
   array('Natraj',HB,"10",HH,12),
   array("Apsara",HB,8,"HH",13),
   array("Camlin",HB,13,HH,13),

   );

for ($row = 0; $row <  3; $row++) {
   echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
   echo "<ul>";
   for ($col = 0; $col <  3; $col++) {
     echo "<li>".$pencil[$row][$col]."</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the output i wanted (based on the idea by @syed qarib, but little modifications):

```
$pencils = array( array("Natraj", "HB", 10, "HH", 12), array("Apsara", "HB", 8, "HH", 9), array("Camlin", "HB", 11, "HH", 13)  );
 for ($pencilSet=0; $pencilSet<3; $pencilSet++){

echo "<ul>";


for($pencilSetDetials=0; $pencilSetDetials<5; $pencilSetDetials++){

if($pencilSetDetials!=0){
echo "<li>" ,$pencils[$pencilSet][$pencilSetDetials], ": Rs." ;
$pencilSetDetials++;
}
echo $pencils[$pencilSet][$pencilSetDetials], "</li>";


}
echo "</ul>";

}
```

Thanks all!